# Returning COUNT() From SOQL Sub-Query

Tags: soql

I have this SOQL statement:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM Assignments)
FROM PermissionSet 
WHERE Id = (an id here)
```

I want to return the count of the results in `(SELECT AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM Assignments)`. The results returned looks to be in JSON format.

I have tried doing

```
SELECT Id, Name, COUNT((SELECT AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM Assignments))
FROM PermissionSet 
WHERE Id = (an id here)
```

but that doesn't work. Is there a way to restructure this query or do I have to write Apex to parse through the JSON?

Comment: Are you working in Apex, or some other language (like Java or PHP) that issues queries through one of the Salesforce APIs?

Comment: @DerekF I'm in Apex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parent-child subquery (also called a left outer join) that you're performing ends up returning a `List<Assignment>`, not JSON. It only looks like JSON when you print it with a debug statement.

```
for(PermissionSet permSet :[<your query here>]){
   // each permission set record has an embedded List<PermissionSetAssignment> with 
   //   your query.
   // Because that's true, the following line will compile
   List<PermissionSetAssignment> children = permSet.Assignments;
}
```

You'd see the same thing if you tried to debug any other `List`.

The nice thing about having the subquery return a `List` is that you can simply call `.size()` on it to get a count of the records.

```
// number of child records is simply the size of the list
permSet.Assignments.size();
```

The one gotcha to look out for is that after a certain, ill-defined, threshold (in number of child records), you may run into the following error

> Aggregate Query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop

In that case, like the error says, you'd need to use a loop to iterate over all the child records for a given parent record. To get the number of child records in this case, you'd need to either increment some variable inside the loop, or store the child records in a collection (`List`, `Map`, or `Set`), and you wouldn't be able to get the count until after that loop finishes.

Some example code of how to handle that situation would be

```
for(PermissionSet permSet :[<your query here>]){
    // Pretend that we'd get an error if we try to access permSet.Assignments directly

    // Declare a list to hold the children
    // This list is re-created on every loop iteration (so Assignments for one
    //   PermissionSet won't be counted towards the number of Assignments for the next
    //   PermissionSet)
    // If you need to keep the PermissionSetAssignment records for all PermissionSets,
    //   then you'd want to use a Map<Id, List<PermissionSetAssignment>> (keyed 
    //   on the Id of the PermissionSet), and you'd want to declare it outside of all loops.
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> children = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();

    for(PermissionSetAssignment permSetAssign : permSet.Assignments){
        // Add the children to the list, one at a time
        children.add(permSetAssign);
    }

    // Now that the (inner) loop is done, we can see how many children there are
    system.debug('number of assignments: ' + children.size());
}
```

Comment: Hm. I tried querying it in anonymous Apex `List<PermissionSet> stuff = [that query]` and when I returned the size of the list, it only has 1.

Comment: @akcorp2003 If you're querying the `PermissionSet` using an Id, then of course you'd only get a maximum of 1 row returned.  The subquery for `Assignment` itself is a `List<Assignment>` embedded into each returned `PermissionSet`. To get the number of assignments, you'd do `suff[0].Assignments.size()`

Comment: Yup! I got the same result as Adrian Larson's answer. After my SOQL statement, I just had `stuff[0].Assignments.size()`.

Comment: So when you say that there is that error, will I have to iterate through the `Assignments` and internally increment a counter to keep track of the number of records?

Comment: @akcorp2003 Yep, or add each `PermissionSetAssignment` record to a separate `List` so you could call `.size()` on it after the loop finishes. I'll edit my answer, adding some example code.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the best answer as I don't need to parse through JSON (though it's not bad at all). Adrian Larson's answer is perfectly valid as well.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want *could* be done, the correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT count() FROM Assignments)
FROM PermissionSet 
WHERE Id = <some_id>
```

But it's not supported. You'll see this error:

> COUNT() can only be used with root queries

However, you could use an aggregate query here, perhaps:

```
SELECT PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, count(Id) records
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE PermissionSetId = '<some_id>'
GROUP BY PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name
```

It will serialize slightly differently, but seems like it should give you what you are looking for. If you add some field aliases, it won't be too dissimilar:

```
system.debug(JSON.serialize([
    SELECT PermissionSetId Id, PermissionSet.Name Name, count(Id) Assignments
    FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE PermissionSetId = '<some_id>'
    GROUP BY PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name
]));
// yields:
[{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "AggregateResult",
        "url": "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/AggregateResult/<some_id>"
    },
    "Id": "<some_id>",
    "Name": "Permission_Set_Name",
    "Assignments": 2
}]
```

Comment: Yup! The SOQL query returns an accurate number. However, the JSON might be a little hairy to parse through. Will this query encounter an error like what DerekF mentioned?

Comment: @akcorp If you have more than 50k assignments, you will hit errors, but no, not the child record count error. You should be able to ignore the `"attributes"` property, for the most part, and any query data you serialize will have that.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the first request would (if it worked) return all permission sets with associated number of assignments (even 0) while the second request won't return permission sets that don't have any assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I think following query will serve your purpose

```
SELECT COUNT(AssigneeId), PermissionSetId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE PermissionSetId IN: permissionSetIds
GROUP BY PermissionSetId
```

For more information, refer [PermissionSetAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm)

Comment: Why do people stick the colon for a bind variable to the operand before it? The operator is `IN`, not `IN:`. The bind variable is `:permissionSetIds`. I wish Salesforce would have made the SOQL parser stricter to only allow the (documented style)[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm].

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNT(Id) and GROUP BY to group the counts. No need to use a sub-query either, if I'm understanding what you're wanting.

You can get data from related objects using the relationship field name with the __r. followed by the related object field you want.

I'm not sure what your data structure is (my org doesn't use Assignments or anything) but here's an example SOQL from my org (which is an academic institution):

```
SELECT Interest_Setup_Record__r.Name, Count(Id) FROM Academic_Plan__c 
    WHERE Interest_Setup_Record__r.Degree_Level__c = 'Masters' 
    GROUP BY Interest_Setup_Record__r.Name
```

This SOQL gets counts for Application Plans for every academic major at the Masters degree level in our institution and displays them grouped by the academic major.

The output looks something like this:

```
Name               | count(Id)
Accounting MBA/MS  |   9 
Anthropology MA/MS |   4
Biology MA/MS      |  12
```

So Biology MA/MS has 12 different academic plan options for students, and so on.

Is that in line with that you're looking to achieve?

Comment: Yes. This is pretty much what I'm looking for. The example SOQL query is something I took from a Salesforce tutorial on PermissionSets.